# why query execution is faster with pdo_oci than with oci8?

Tags: php, pdo, oci8

I'm connecting to my Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit.

Connecting with php 5.6.3 (xampp installation).

Simple query execution is instanteneous with pdo_oci.

It takes 5 seconds with oci8.

For pdo_oci, i use extension php_pdo_oci.dll

For oci8, i use extension php_oci8_12c.dll

I've installed oracle instantclient_12_1.

Here's the code for pdo_oci :

```
$hote = '123.456.789.3';
$port = '1521';
$service = 'blabla.blabla-db.blabla';
$user = '12345';
$pass = '12345';

$lien_base =
"oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS =
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (Host = ".$hote .")
        (Port = ".$port."))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVICE_NAME = ".$service.")
)
)";

try
{
    $connexion = new PDO($lien_base, $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $erreur)
{
    echo $erreur->getMessage();
}

$num_notice = "030000002";
$notice = $connexion->query("SELECT * FROM UDQ01.Z13U WHERE Z13U_REC_KEY = ".$connexion->quote($num_notice)."")->fetch();

echo '<pre>' . print_r($notice,1) . '</pre>';
```

And the code for oci8 :

```
$conn = oci_connect('12345', '12345', '123.456.211.3:1521/blabla.blabla-db.blabla.ca');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM UDQ01.Z13U WHERE Z13U_REC_KEY = 030000002';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);

$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($row,1) . '</pre>';

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Why is it so slow with oci8 ?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: Maybe one of the tests hits the query cache, while the other one was run when the database was 'cold'.

Comment: No, it's always faster with pdo_oci.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the query :

There should have ' between the value, like :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM UDQ01.Z13U WHERE Z13U_REC_KEY = '030000002'";
```

The ' was implicit with pdo_oci query :

```
"SELECT * FROM UDQ01.Z13U WHERE Z13U_REC_KEY = ".$connexion->quote($num_notice).""
```

So pdo_oci and oci8 are equally fast.